# "The semaphore timeout period has expired" on connect to MS SQLServer inside WIndows Container

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have faced with very strange issue. 
Host OS is Windows 10 Pro, installed Docker for Windows. 
When I run [microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer/) container using simple command

```
docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e sa_password=<SA_PASSWORD> -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer
```

I can connect to SQL Server via MS SQL Management Studio using server name=localhost. But I can't open Server Properties or open "Attach DB" wizard. There is the same error all the time "The semaphore timeout period has expired". 
I can run container with attached DBs and I can execute sql inside MS SQL Management Studio. But when I run my Web Application - I get the same error "The semaphore timeout period has expired" on connect to DB.

Then I tried to connect to SQL Server using IP address which I get via docker container inspect - in my case it was 172.28.93.83. And everything worked as it should - I can manage with SQL Server, my Web Application connects to the DB, etc.

So, what is the issue there? I still want to use localhost to connect to server to have unified connection string in all developers environments.

When I tried to run Linux container - everything worked fine using localhost to connect to server.

I could be important - before I decided to use docker to work with MS SQL Server I had MS SQL Server installed and then uninstalled it. Maybe it made some changes in a routing or network which I have to remove...

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Did you manage to find what the issue was?

Comment: Nope. I've decided to not use Windows containers. I remember that I could connect but via another ip address, not localhost. But don't remember details.

Answer (score 0):

Try with increase timeout seconds in `connection string`.

Comment: Didn't help. It gets stuck somewhere and I can't understand where it happens. Will try to do it in a fresh installed Windows.

Answer (score -1):

I solved a similar incident changing the metric to the card generated by Docker.
I put 5000.
Luck.